# Google analytic not showing android event values

Tags: android, events, google-analytics

Hi I am working with Google Analytic with android application. I am creating some custom events. Its working fine. Only thing it is not showing event value which I am sending along with event. It is showing my event in real time but only showing category and action but not showing its value.

I tried it in following way:

```
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(category)
            .setValue(value)
            .setLabel(label)
            .setAction(action)
            .build());
```

Am I doing any thing wrong? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: My events are coming in real time events but not showing in events under behaviour on anylytic dashboard

Comment: I believe the event values are not available in real time. You should be able to see the value is Behavior > Events > Overview + Select category or label.